# how to make a slide slips from left to right?

Tags: slide, right-to-left

i coded a slide to slip left to right but i don't know why it just runs once time, it does run a first image again when it run last image.Anyone help me,sorry for my bad english. hope you undertands.

**HTML**

> ```
>   <img src="Britney-Spears.jpg" class="img" />
>   <img src="Britney-Spears-101[1].JPG" class="img" />
>   <img src="Britney-Spears-Wallpaper-18.jpg" class="img" />
>    </div>
> ```

**CSS**

> .neoslideshow {position:relative; width:500px; height:260px;
>   background:#0C9; overflow:hidden;} .neoslideshow img
>   {position:absolute; top:0;width:400px;  height:260px;}

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$('.neoslideshow img:gt(0)').css('left',-500);
function slide()
{
    $('.neoslideshow :first-child').animate({left:"+=500"},"slow").css('left',-500)
    .next('img').animate({left:"+=500"},"slow").css('left',-500)
    .end().appendTo('.neoslideshow');



};
setInterval(function(){slide();},2000);

});
```